# Remix: Unable to get formData from the routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, remix.run

Working with a remix project which is trying to receive data from the form. When I receive the form data from my React component, I am unable to retrieve any fields from `formData.get`.

Here is my code in the route,

```js
export async function action(data: any) {
    const { request } = data;

    console.log(`request`);
    console.log(request);

    const formData = await request.formData();

    console.log(`formData`);
    console.log(formData);
    
    const noteData: Note = {
        title: formData.get("title")?.toString() ?? "",
        description: formData.get("description")?.toString() ?? "",
    };
    const note = createNote(noteData);
    console.log(`New note created => Note - ${JSON.stringify(note)}`);
}
```

Above I have added some log statements as well. Noticing that `formData` is returning an empty object.

```
formData
formData {}
```

How can this be fixed so that I can retrieve the form data?

EDIT:
Adding the React Component below which uses the action,

```
    export default function Note() {
        return (
            <form method="post" action="/notes" id="quote-form">
                <p>
                    <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label htmlFor="content">Content</label>
                    <textarea id="content" name="content" required />
                </p>
                <div>
                    <button> Add Note </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );

}
```

The route is shown above with the function name `action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.formData` returns a Promise, `await` it.

Example:

```js
export async function action(data: any) {
  const { request } = data;

  ...

  const formData = await request.formData();

  ...
}
```

Additionally, you cannot simply console log a `FormData` object to get the field data, but instead you'll need to access its field data.

Examples:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.set("foo", 123);
formData.set("bar", "barbar");
formData.append("foo", 456);

console.log("formData", formData); // no field data
console.log("get foo", formData.get("foo"));
console.log("getAll foo", formData.getAll("foo"));
console.log("get entries", ...formData.entries());
```

The form you are submitting doesn't have a "description" field, it has `title` and `content` fields.

```
export default function Note() {
  return (
    <form method="post" action="/notes" id="quote-form">
      <p>
        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor="content">Content</label>
        <textarea id="content" name="content" required />
      </p>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Add Note</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

```js
export async function action(data: any) {
  const { request } = data;

  const formData = await request.formData();

  console.log("formData", ...formData.entries());
    
  const noteData: Note = {
    title: formData.get("title")?.toString() ?? "",
    description: formData.get("content")?.toString() ?? "",
  };

  const note = createNote(noteData);
  console.log(`New note created => Note - ${JSON.stringify(note)}`);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have tried that and the form data at this point is empty. 
`formData
FormData {}`

Comment: @Ahmed I see, then there may be some issue submitting a form action. Can you edit the post to include your UI routed code submitting the action? You may just need to console log the form data differently, e.g. `formData.get("field")` and then log the field.

Comment: Added the component which uses the action

Comment: `FormData` is a special object and you can't just `console.log` it. You can use `Object.fromEntries(formData)` to get an object. But note that with FormData, you can have multiple entries with the same name. You typically get that from formData.getAll(name). With Object.fromEntries(), you will only get the last one of the multiple values.

Comment: Agreed with @Kiliman, and this is what I meant or was suggesting with accessing fields from the `formData` object instead of trying to console log the entire object itself.

Comment: Thank you. I have made the change and now I am able to see the values from form data. Next is my Prisma client not working. One issue after another lol :)

Comment: Thanks Kiliman. So it means that in order to get all the same fields I need to use formData.getAll('<fieldname>');. Great tip. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Make you function async and await the form data:

```
export async function action(data: any) {
    const { request } = data;

    console.log(`request`);
    console.log(request);

    const formData = await request.formData();
```